# Append a line in BASH only on certain lines

Tags: bash, awk, sed, nagios

I am working on a script to make changes to a Nagios plugin service definition using BASH. I need to append the contact group name line but only for certain service definitions. So I would start with this.

```
define service {
    use                     sites-service
    host_name               my_host
    service_description     check_reboot_os_updates
    check_command           check_reboot_os_updates
    contact_groups          contactgroup1
    servicegroups           MyGroup
    }
    
define service {
        use                     linux-service
        host_name               my_host
        service_description     other_description
        check_command           other_command
        contact_groups          contactgroup1
        servicegroups           MyGroup
        }
```

And I want to append only select contact group lines. So say I wanted to add an additional contact group to the Linux services like this.

```
define service {
        use                     sites-service
        host_name               my_host
        service_description     check_reboot_os_updates
        check_command           check_reboot_os_updates
        contact_groups          contactgroup1
        servicegroups           MyGroup
        }
        
define service {
        use                     linux-service
        host_name               my_host
        service_description     other_description
        check_command           other_command
        contact_groups          contactgroup1, contactgroup2
        servicegroups           MyGroup
        }
```

Is there a way I can do this using sed or awk or something else?

Comment: Why is the second block further indented?

Comment: It's probably just the way I copy and pasted in to the form. There is no particular reason for it and it wouldn't be further indented in the site template.

Comment: Please add to your question (no comment): What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `sed`, if the string `linux-service` is unique, you can try matching from the line containing the string to the line containing the string `contact_groups` appending the additional group within the match.

```
$ sed '/linux-service/,/contact_groups/s/contact_groups.*/&, contactgroup2/' input_file
define service {
        use                     sites-service
        host_name               my_host
        service_description     check_reboot_os_updates
        check_command           check_reboot_os_updates
        contact_groups          contactgroup1
        servicegroups           MyGroup
        }

define service {
        use                     linux-service
        host_name               my_host
        service_description     other_description
        check_command           other_command
        contact_groups          contactgroup1, contactgroup2
        servicegroups           MyGroup
```

Comment: That worked perfectly. The only thing I had to change was add -i after sed so it persisted. Thank you for your response.

Comment: @JimMiller You're welcome. I was not aware of the in place requirement, apologies.

Comment: no worries. You got me over the most difficult part. Have a great day.

Answer (score 1):

with [awk](/questions/tagged/awk)

```sh
awk '
  $1 == "use" {use = $2}
  use == "linux-service" && $1 == "contact_groups" {$0 = $0 ", contactgroup2"}
  {print}
' file
```

To update the file:

- `gawk -i inplace '...' file`
- `awk '...' file | sponge file` -- requires `moreutils` package
- `f=$(mktemp); awk '...' file > "$f" && mv "$f" file`